# SQL Query, how to know if is resource intensive? I/O

Tags: sql-server, performance-tuning, database-tuning

I am not a SQL guru, but I am troubleshooting an issue with our marketing platform as its become slugish and slow, I've requested the top 50 heavy/resource intensive queries executed on our sql server to correlate with our marketing workflows.

Here is an example or some of the top queries, based on the average I/O would you say these queries are consuming too much resources? whats a normal acceptable IO for a query?

[image]

If I take the first query execution plan, it will be as following.

[image]

[image]

Plan Link https://www.brentozar.com/PasteThePlan/?id=HJtGXHxUc

Comment: Can you please get the **actual** execution plan and upload it to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/PasteThePlan)? It has a lot more important information coded in it that isn't visible in a screenshot.

Comment: Also some information on how long it takes to execute that query now and how long it used to run in when it was fast would be helpful. The query itself is also always a good idea to include too.

Comment: I think these plan was grabbed from the cache, Isnt this the actual execution plan?

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/PasteThePlan/?id=HJtGXHxUc

Comment: Honestly it's hard for me to tell from a screenshot, so if you could please upload it to Paste The Plan as mentioned in my first comment, that would help get your post rolling.

Comment: that first query has an average io of 265k

Comment: But actually yes coming from the Plan Cache that's still not the full actual plan, which I'm able to confirm by looking at the plan you've linked in your comment above. It only has estimated metrics not actuals in it unfortunately. You'd have to run the query yourself with the actual execution plan enabled. Unfortunately most times the estimated plan doesn't tell much.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I love getting actual plans because estimated vs. actual is a huge measure. But to say that the plan from cache doesn't tell much, that's just not true. It shows exactly what the optimizer thought it was going to do and did. There's tons of information in there, all of identical to what get when you add the runtime metrics in an actual plan.

Comment: @GrantFritchey Eh I don't disagree, and didn't necessarily say the plan from the cache doesn't tell much, just specifically it doesn't have the runtime metrics, which is what I find useful to start with. Agreed it's better than just a generic estimated plan though.

Comment: Where in the database is the actual plan stored? I wonder why they provided me with estimated rather than actual.

Comment: @DavidGarcia The *full* actual plan XML with runtime metrics isn't stored anywhere (I believe), because you can get different metrics on each run (such as how long a particular operator took on that instance of execution). As I previously mentioned, you'd have to run the query yourself with the actual execution plan enabled. That being said, Grant's answer likely points you in the right direction of where your bottlenecks are regardless.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a value that is good, or bad, for a query. It completely depends on what the query is doing. SELECT * from a table without a WHERE clause from a table with billions of rows will have a very high level of I/O. Whereas, SELECT ID from a table with a WHERE clause on the ID column and a clustered index on the ID column will have about as low a level of I/O as it's possible to get. Neither is right or wrong and there's not a >42 is bad kind of measure here.

Instead, you have to look at the query and what it's doing. Then, look at the execution plan to see how the query is being resolved.

In this case, you have a table scan, meaning it's a heap with no clustered index, even though there are clear WHERE clause values that could use an index to find data. So either the heap doesn't haven any nonclustered indexes, or, the nonclustered indexes it has, don't support the query. Does this mean there is excessive I/O going on? Yeah, probably.

Additionally, you have a nonclustered index in use, skypipeline_eventid, but it's not a covering index because then you have an RID lookup (another heap table). Is this excessive I/O? Yeah, probably.

In general, the vast majority of your tables should have clustered indexes. Indications are, this database has none, or few (sample size of 2 ain't exactly dispositive). Without clustered indexes on the column(s) that define the most commonly used path to the data, you're doing nothing but table scans all over the place. So, yeah, you're probably experiencing excessive I/O.

Comment: "*the vast majority of your tables should have clustered indexes*" - absolutely agreed despite my next sentence. This is where having the runtime metrics makes me feel better to analyze this. I personally can't say for sure it's excessive I/O unless I see the runtime metrics confirming it was actually that expensive instead of the actual number of rows read / returned were significantly less making the Heap scans insignificant (e.g. in a cardinality mis-estimate scenario). I'm sure you're spot on though and I agree with this answer. Also your query plan experience surely surpasses mine. 

Comment: Thanks for the insight.

Comment: @J.D. No arguments from me. If I can get the runtime metrics, I want 'em. They make a real difference. Knowing the accuracy of the estimates is there in the plan. Otherwise, you have to go dig that information up, and I'm far too lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Theory: To know for certain if a batch (not a query, but the entire set of queries) is excessive, you must first know for certain that it can be better.  This is most perfectly proven by opening up the batch and writing it in a different way that is - according to Extended Events or Profiler Logical Reads, Writes, CPU, and Duration for the SQL:BatchCompleted event - better in all possible cases of input parameters.

If a query can be better, then whatever is worse is excessive.

In practice it's fuzzier the better your database and code.  A horrifically written set of queries on a horrific schema (see Grant's mention of clustered indexes, etc.) is easy to spot and easy to make better in every possible way.  A pretty good query on a pretty good schema tends to lead to tradeoffs - a different way of writing it is better in 60% of cases and worse in 40%, but what if your workload is mostly those 40% during the busiest times of days, and mostly the 60% during otherwise less busy times?

For a simple practical answer: Turn on Extended Events for a minute for SQL:BatchCompleted with no filters saved to a file, with Multiple Statement Loss allowed, watch performance for all your users while it's on, then turn it off.  Look at Logical Reads, writes, CPU, and maybe duration if you care.  Heck, throw in Physical Reads too at this stage.

- If the one minute test is ok, you can try a few minutes; work your way up slowly, and DO NOT leave it on a production machine.

Now you have ACTUAL results; moreover, if you look at the Statement or Sql_text or batch_text fields, you have an actual runnable statement including the parameters that were sent to SQL.

- First, sort by Statement/Sql_text/batch_text, and see if the apps are sending the SAME statement with the SAME parameters repeatedly.

  - If those are batches that return identical results over and over, start the process of getting the Marketing app people on it now... because it typically takes forever for the app to get changed.  The easiest way to improve SQL performance is to give it less work.
- Then you do - once, probably - the fairly rare step of can sort by Physical Reads; if you're OFTEN or USUALLY doing a high percentage of physical reads compared to logical...

  - adding RAM is the hardware to throw at it if that's easy for you to give you a little more performance WHILE you're tuning things.
  - Adding correct indexing might ALSO solve this completely, especially if you're lacking appropriate clustered and nonclustered indexes - if SQL has to read 100GB of data when it should be only reading 12MB, well, you're going to blow through your buffer memory really really fast, causing excessive pointless disk IO.
  - Tuning might also help it, same reason as above.
- Now sort by Logical Reads and CPU one at a time; you'll need to know what's your actual likely bottleneck.  Most systems it's logical reads.  Some systems - usually poorly designed or drastically underresourced - it's CPU.

  - Look at the top biggest queries; of those, find the ones that are called frequently.  Big AND frequent is the first things to look at.

    - The ACTUAL key is aggregate load over time during peak time, but for your first look, just go for what looks big.
  - Open them up.

    - First, fix obvious problems.  If it's doing a JOIN on something non-unique and then a DISTINCT on the results when a better join gives perfectly accurate data without the DISTINCT, fix it.  Again, make SQL do LESS work - less columns used, less rows used by the total batch.  Only what is actually necessary.  Quit putting columns in #temp or derived tables that aren't necessary to end results.  Etc.
    - Then, write them differently - at least two or three different ways.  With #temp tables, without, different joins, whatever other techniques you think might work.  Use Extended Events or Profiler on a test system to compare them.

      - Remember parameter sniffing - ALTER PROCEDURE or sp_recompile or use DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (On your test system, NOT on production) to reset the query plan cache each time, "prime" it with a different inital query.
    - Now, determine which indexes - and which column order for multi-column indexes - might help.  Add one, test the variations, drop the index and add another.

      - Every index means more writes, more space, slower maintenance, bigger backups, etc.
      - Study how SQL uses multi-column indexing.  Watch it in query plans.

After you do the above for a few queries in the same general domain of the database, you'll start to see common issues; you'll start to get a feel for what is excessive.  You'll be able to look at a query and go "Hey, to get X, I think taking 100,000 reads is way too much; it's excessive."

It's experience with YOUR system that leads you there; when you look at a new system, you have to start over, but you've got a better base to work from.